# how to align items in column in flutter to start from same place?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

i want to align the items in my list  and i want them to start from the same place and i don't know how.??

[image: here its my app screen]
[image: here its what i want]

and its my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Image.network(url),
        TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Show Details')),
        const Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            Text('order : Late'),
            Text(r'price : 10$'),
            Text('ingredient : milk - butter - coffee ')
          ],
```

i hope you understand  what i meant.
thank you for helping me.

i hope you understand  what i meant.
thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is add:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

To your Column widget, it will be like this:

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          // rest of the code)
```